# Show/Hide Menu fade in/out from right side problem css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, navigation

I am having problems with my navigation sidebar.
At first worked properly but I don't know what I did and I can't see the problem.
The menu doesn't fade in and out from the right side anymore when the menu button is clicked.
I've been trying to solve this for days now. Can anyone help me, please?

```js
$(function() {
   App.init();
});
var App = {
   init: function() {
      this.side.nav(), this.navigation(), this.hyperlinks(), setInterval("App.datetime();", 1e3)
   },
   side: {
      nav: function() {
         this.toggle(), this.navigation()
      },
      toggle: function() {
         $(".ion-ios-navicon").on("touchstart click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(), $(".sidebar").toggleClass("active"), $(".nav").removeClass("active"), $(".sidebar .sidebar-overlay").removeClass("fadeOut animated").addClass("fadeIn animated")
         }), $(".sidebar .sidebar-overlay").on("touchstart click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(), $(".ion-ios-navicon").click(), $(this).removeClass("fadeIn").addClass("fadeOut")
         })
      },
      navigation: function() {
         $(".nav-right a").on("touchstart click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var t = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
            $(".sidebar").toggleClass("active"), $(".html").removeClass("visible"), "home" == t || "" == t || null == t ? $(".html.welcome").addClass("visible") : $(".html." + t).addClass("visible"), App.title($(this).text())
         })
      }
   }
};
var pagos = document.getElementById("pagos");
var perfil = document.getElementById("perfil");
pagos.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("ProfileBody").style.display = "none";
};
perfil.onclick = function() {
 document.getElementById("ProfileBody").style.display = "block";
};
```

```css
html {
  background: rgb(131,58,180);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(131,58,180,1) 0%, rgba(253,29,29,1) 50%, rgba(252,176,69,1) 100%);
}

.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
  content: '';
  display: table
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block
}

.mobile .header {
 z-index:999;
 position:relative;
  top: 20px;
}

.mobile .header .ion-ios-arrow-back {
  min-width: 25px
}

.mobile .header .ion-ios-navicon>i {
  height: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block
}

.mobile .header .ion-ios-navicon>i:after,
.mobile .header .ion-ios-navicon>i:before {
  content: '';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  background: inherit
}

.mobile .header .ion-ios-navicon>i:before {
  bottom: 12px
}

.mobile .header .ion-ios-navicon>i:after {
  bottom: 6px
}

.mobile .header  {
 outline:none;
}
.mobile .header,
.mobile .header  {
 -webkit-appearance:none;
}
.mobile .header {
 width:100%;
 border-bottom-color:#aaa;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left
}

.pull-right {
  float: right
}

.html {
  display: none
}

.html.visible,
.visible {
  display: block
}

.sidebar .sidebar-content,
.sidebar .sidebar-overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s
}

.sidebar .sidebar-overlay {
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 50%;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);

}

.sidebar .sidebar-content {
display: none;
  width: 50%;
  color: #333;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: rgb(131,58,180);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(131,58,180,1) 0%, rgba(253,29,29,1) 50%, rgba(252,176,69,1) 100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200%);
          transform: translateX(200%)
}

.sidebar.active .sidebar-content {

  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
          transform: translateX(50%);
}

.sidebar.active .sidebar-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1)
}

.sidebar .sidebar-content .top-head>span  {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}

.sidebar .sidebar-content .nav-right>a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  line-height: 24px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-decoration: none
}

.sidebar .sidebar-content .nav-right>a>span {
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  min-width: 40px;
  display: inline-block
}

.html.chats,
.html.search,
.html.compose,
.html.credits,
.html.settings,
.html.welcome {
  margin-top: 70px
}

.on-off {
  display: none
}

.on-off+label {
  width: 30px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #dedee0;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s
}

.on-off+label:after {
  left: 0;
  top: -2px;
  width: 15px;
  content: '';
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #bebdc2;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s
}

.on-off:checked+label {
  background: #fd99b3
}

.on-off:checked+label:after {
  left: 15px;
  background: #fb3666
}

.btn {
  color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  background: #cf0e3f;
  border-radius: 30px
}
 .title{
 font-size:24px;
}
.title p{
 margin:0;
 font-size:16px;
 line-height:18px;
}

.alarm-list {
  margin-top: 70px
}

.alarm-list .note {
  padding: 10px 0
}

.alarm-list .note:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .2s;
  animation-duration: .2s
}

.alarm-list .note:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-duration: .3s
}

.alarm-list .note:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;
  animation-duration: .4s
}

.alarm-list .note .time {
  min-width: 35px;
  margin-right: 30px
}

.alarm-list .note .time>.shift,
.alarm-list .note .to-do>.subject {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 11px
}

.alarm-list .note .time {
  text-align: center
}

.alarm-list .note .to-do>.title {
  font-size: 14px
}

.alarm-list .note:not(:last-child) {
  position: relative
}

.alarm-list .note:not(:last-child):before {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 82%;
  content: '';
  right: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(170, 170, 170, .5)
}

.user-list .user {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #bbb
}

.user-list .user>img {
  width: 100%
}

.compose .forms .group {
  margin-bottom: 15px
}

.compose .forms .group>label {
  padding: 6px 0;
  min-width: 40px;
  display: inline-block
}

.compose .forms .group>label>span {
  min-width: 20px;
  display: inline-block
}

.compose .forms .group input,
.compose .forms .group textarea {
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  min-width: 185px;
  background: 0 0;
  padding: 5px 10px 1px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(170, 170, 170, .6)
}

.compose .forms .visible {
  width: 100%;
  display: block!important
}

.compose .forms .action {
  margin-top: 50px
}

.compose .forms .group:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .1s;
  animation-duration: .1s
}

.compose .forms .group:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .2s;
  animation-duration: .2s
}

.compose .forms .group:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-duration: .3s
}

.compose .forms .group:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;
  animation-duration: .4s
}

.chats .tabs-list {
  margin-bottom: 15px
}

.chats .tabs-list .tab {
  float: left;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent
}

.chats .tabs-list .tab.active,
.chats .tabs-list .tab:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid
}

.chats .active-users .user {
  padding: 5px 0;
  cursor: default
}

.chats .active-users .photo {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)
}

.chats .active-users .photo img {
  width: 100%
}

.chats .active-users .desc {
  margin-left: 15px
}

.chats .active-users .desc p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px
}

.chats .active-users .desc {
  font-weight: 400
}

.chats .active-users .desc .position {
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 12px
}

.chats .active-users .user .idle {
  height: 40px;
  position: relative
}

.chats .active-users .user .idle>span {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #fff
}

.chats .active-users .user .idle>.online {
  background: #2ecc71
}

.chats .active-users .user .idle>.offline {
  background: #95a5a6
}

.chats .active-users .user .idle>.away {
  background: #f2ca27
}

.chats .active-users .user:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .18s;
  animation-duration: .18s
}

.chats .active-users .user:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .25s;
  animation-duration: .25s
}

.chats .active-users .user:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .35s;
  animation-duration: .35s
}

.chats .active-users .user:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;
  animation-duration: .4s
}

.chats .active-users .user:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-duration: .5s
}

.chats .active-users .user:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .6s;
  animation-duration: .6s
}

.chats .active-users .user .idle>span:before {
  right: 20px;
  bottom: -2px;
  display: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  content: attr(class);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  text-transform: capitalize
}

.chats .active-users .user:hover .idle>span:before {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .4s;
  animation: fadeInRight .4s
}

.profile {
  display: block;
  border: solid black 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right:2px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.profile .photo {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.profile .photo img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s
}

.profile .details .user-name {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

.setting-list {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px
}

.setting-list .gear {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400
}

.setting-list .gear:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(170, 170, 170, .4)
}

.setting-list .gear>.action {
  color: #aaa
}

.setting-list .gear:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .1s;
  animation-duration: .1s
}

.setting-list .gear:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .2s;
  animation-duration: .2s
}

.setting-list .gear:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
  animation-duration: .3s
}

.setting-list .gear:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;
  animation-duration: .4s
}

.setting-list .gear:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
  animation-duration: .5s
}

.setting-list .gear:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-duration: .6s;
  animation-duration: .6s
}
.body-profile {
  display: block;
  border: solid black 1px;
  position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.imagenCoche {
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Usuario Conectado</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="mobile-wrap">
 <div class="mobile clearfix">
    <div class="header">
      <span class="ion-ios-navicon pull-left"><i></i></span>
      <span id="navicon" class="pull-right"></span>
    </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
   <div id="menu" class="sidebar-overlay"></div>
   <div class="sidebar-content">
    <div class="top-head"><span>Menu</span>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right">
     <a id="perfil" href="#profile"><span class="ion-ios-person-outline"></span>Perfil</a>
     <a id="pagos" href="#alarm"><span class="ion-ios-list-outline"></span>Pagos</a>
     <a href="#compose"><span class="ion-ios-compose-outline"></span>Compose</a>
     <a href="#chats"><span class="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline"></span>Chats</a>
     <a href="#settings"><span class="ion-ios-gear-outline"></span>Settings</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
    <div class="html profile visible">
      <div class="photo flipInX animated">
        <img src="img/woman.png">
      </div>
      <div class="details">
        <p class="user-name">
          <span class="name">Jhon Doe</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ProfileBody" class="body-profile">
<img class="imagenCoche" src="img/coche.jpg"></img>
</div>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="html alarm">
    <div class="alarm-list">
     <div class="note clearfix slideInRight animated">
      <div class="time pull-left">
       <div class="hour">9</div>
       <div class="shift">AM</div>
      </div>
      <div class="to-do pull-left">
       <div class="title">Finish HTML Coding</div>
       <div class="subject">Web UI</div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="note clearfix slideInRight animated">
      <div class="time pull-left">
       <div class="hour">1</div>
       <div class="shift">PM</div>
      </div>
      <div class="to-do pull-left">
       <div class="title">Lunch Break</div>
       <div class="subject"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="note clearfix slideInRight animated" data-revert="slideOutRight">
      <div class="time pull-left">
       <div class="hour">3</div>
       <div class="shift">PM</div>
      </div>
      <div class="to-do pull-left">
       <div class="title">Design Stand Up</div>
       <div class="subject">Hangouts</div>
       <div class="user-list clearfix">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="html compose">
    <div class="forms">
     <div class="group clearfix slideInRight animated">
      <label class="pull-left" for="compose-time"><span class="ion-ios-time-outline"></span> Time</label>
      <input class="pull-right" id="compose-time" type="time">
     </div>
     <div class="group clearfix slideInLeft animated">
      <label class="pull-left" for="compose-date"><span class="ion-ios-calendar-outline"></span> Date</label>
      <input class="pull-right" id="compose-date" type="date">
     </div>
     <div class="group clearfix slideInRight animated">
      <label class="pull-left" for="compose-title"><span class="ion-ios-paper-outline"></span> Title</label>
      <input class="pull-right" id="compose-title" type="text">
     </div>
     <div class="group clearfix slideInLeft animated">
      <label class="visible" for="compose-detail"><span class="ion-ios-list-outline"></span> Task</label>
      <textarea class="visible" id="compose-detail" rows="3"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="action flipInY animated">
      <button class="btn">Compose</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="html chats">
    <div class="tabs-list clearfix">
     <a href="#" class="tab active">Users</a>
     <a href="#" class="tab">Messages</a>
     <a href="#" class="tab">Groups</a>
    </div>
    <div class="active-users">
     <div class="user clearfix rotateInDownLeft animated">
      <div class="photo pull-left">
       <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="desc pull-left">
       <p class="name">Connor Hartigan</p>
       <p class="position">Web &amp; UI Designer</p>
      </div>
      <div class="idle pull-right"><span class="away"></span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="user clearfix rotateInDownRight animated">
      <div class="photo pull-left">
       <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/markmushiva/128.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="desc pull-left">
       <p class="name">Jacob Lennon</p>
       <p class="position">Front-End Developer</p>
      </div>
      <div class="idle pull-right"><span class="offline"></span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="user clearfix rotateInDownLeft animated">
      <div class="photo pull-left">
       <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/scottohara/128.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="desc pull-left">
       <p class="name">Didier Mailly</p>
       <p class="position">Co-Founder</p>
      </div>
      <div class="idle pull-right"><span class="away"></span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="user clearfix rotateInDownRight animated">
      <div class="photo pull-left">
       <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/shalt0ni/128.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="desc pull-left">
       <p class="name">Miguel Cunha Ferreira</p>
       <p class="position">Sales Manager</p>
      </div>
      <div class="idle pull-right"><span class="online"></span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="user clearfix rotateInDownLeft animated">
      <div class="photo pull-left">
       <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/sircookieface/128.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="desc pull-left">
       <p class="name">Eric Yuriev</p>
       <p class="position">App Developer</p>
      </div>
      <div class="idle pull-right"><span class="online"></span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="user clearfix rotateInDownRight animated">
      <div class="photo pull-left">
       <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ryanmclaughlin/128.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="desc pull-left">
       <p class="name">Theodore Clark</p>
       <p class="position">Project Manager</p>
      </div>
      <div class="idle pull-right"><span class="online"></span></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="html settings">
    <div class="setting-list">
     <div class="gear clearfix slideInRight animated">
      <div class="title pull-left">General</div>
      <div class="action pull-right"><span class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="gear clearfix slideInLeft animated">
      <div class="title pull-left"><label for="gear-notice">Notification</label></div>
      <div class="action pull-right"><input id="gear-notice" class="on-off" type="checkbox"><label for="gear-notice"></label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="gear clearfix slideInRight animated">
      <div class="title pull-left"><label for="gear-sound">Sound</label></div>
      <div class="action pull-right"><input id="gear-sound" class="on-off" type="checkbox" checked><label for="gear-sound"></label></div>
     </div>
     <div class="gear clearfix slideInLeft animated">
      <div class="title pull-left">Theme</div>
      <div class="action pull-right">Standard <span class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="gear clearfix slideInRight animated">
      <div class="title pull-left">Support</div>
      <div class="action pull-right"><span class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="gear clearfix slideInLeft animated">
      <div class="title pull-left">Privacy</div>
      <div class="action pull-right"><span class="ion-ios-arrow-right"></span></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's an issue with you jquery code that is this.navigation. The error says it all.

Comment: I don't understand what is the issue. I'm a beginner at javascript so I don't understand what is the issue. Can you be more specific?

Comment: What have you tried doing so far?

Comment: At first I thought it's from css so I tried there with "display" settings. If i set it to "display:none" the menu doesn't fade in when clicked. And if there are no display settings at all the sidebar is visible all the time. In JavaScript I tried this: navicon.onclick = function() {
 document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "block";
};